# Modifying an array inside a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I have this function that tries to remove non-alphabetic characters, however my code is not working. I tried to debug it and it seems that it is stuck on this line :

```
str[i]= str[i+1];
```

Can someone please explain me why it is stuck there?

Thank you.

```
int Removenonalfa(char *str) {
    int i =0;

    while (str[i]!='\0')
    {
        j=0;
        if ((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') || (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'))
        ;
        else
        {

            str[i]= str[i+1];
            continue;

        }


        i++;
    }
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What exactly means "*it is stuck on this line*"? How exactly do you detect this? The line `str[i]= str[i+1];` copies one character and leaves the remaining string as is. For example from `abc123def` you would get `abc23ddef` (after removing `continue` as others pointed out). You probably need two independent index variables for the character you read / check and for the position to write.

Comment: Aside:  `j = 0;`  `j` is not declared.

Comment: As already suggested, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73458925/edit) your post! Add a [mcve], so everyone can really help you.

Answer (score 3):

The `continue;` prevents the rest of the loop body from being executed, so `i++;` is never executed, so `i` never changes, so the loop continues with the same value of `i` forever.

You should rethink how you structure the loop. You have written it with one indicator of position in the string, `i`. But, since you want to remove non-letter characters and return a string with letter characters, what you really want to do is read each character in the string, and, if it is a letter, move it to its final place in the string. So you need two indicators of position. You have a `j` that is not used. Rewrite the loop so that `i` progresses through the string one character at a time—it is always incremented by one in each iteration, and you never skip that increment. Use `j` to track where each letter will be written to in the string. Then `j` will increment only when a letter is processed.

Comment: However, it has done `str[i] = str[i + 1];` before the `continue;`, which should affect the `while` condition.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Not when the new character, from `str[i+1]`, also does not satisfy the test.

Comment: Exactly, but that needs pointing out in the answer.

Comment: @IanAbbott tried to put j=1 between the statement and the continue; however the j was never equal to 1. I did a debug using codeblocks software

Comment: @IanAbbott: Not really, the more important issue is moving the letter characters correctly.

Comment: I tried like you told me and it is still the same behavior:

void Removenonalfa1(char *str)
{
    int i =0;
    int j =0;

    while (str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if ((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') || (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'))
        {
            str[j]= str[i];
            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }
    str[j]='\0';

}
<pre> <code>

Comment: As you are initializing `int i = 1;`and incrementing (`i++`) for each iteration, is it then not better for use a for loop? `for( int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ ) { /* .. */ }`

Comment: @tonyjk: When I execute the code you show in the comment, it completes and behaves as expected. Ensure you are compiling and executing the code you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
void KeepAlphabeticChars(char *str)
{
    int writer = 0, reader = 0;

    while (s[reader])
    {
        if ((str[reader]>='A' && str[reader]<='Z') || (str[reader]>='a' && str[reader]<='z'))
        {   
            str[writer++] = str[reader];
        }

        reader++;       
    }

    str[writer]=0;
}
```

you need to declare your string like this:

```
char str[] = "ab12cdef";
```

Comment: Calling `strlen` and `memmove` for every character to remove is a fairly inefficient implementation.

Comment: I tried this code and I am getting the same result the code is stuck on the line str[writer++] = str[reader];

Comment: weird, maybe that comes from a special character in your str ?

Comment: I am trying this one char *c = {"a1bcd"};

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/OTvwTDZ9U

Comment: can you try with the word declared like this char c[] = "a1bcd";  ?

Comment: yes with your code and the declaration i say above it works, but you have your "1" replaced by a "b", replace by my code and you'll be ok

Comment: yes it worked. but why?

I mean when I replaced char*c with char c[]

Comment: because of what's mentioned on the other answers, char *c declares it as a pointer on a char, and char c[] as an array of chars, and i assume you want to work with the second option

Comment: I updated it on my answer to make sure it's clear ;)

Comment: but they should be equivalent no?

Comment: "The main difference between them is that the first is an array and the other one is a pointer. The array owns its contents, which happen to be a copy, while the pointer simply refers to the contents of the string (which in this case is immutable)."

Comment: So your function worked but that's the way you declared the variable that was wrong

Comment: @tonyjk "but they should be equivalent no?" No. They are not. The pointer version may point to read only memory and make a mess. You should use `const char *s = "test";` for strings you don't need to modify and `char s[] = "test";` for those you may modify. Still, pay attention to their size.

Comment: @Costantino Grana ahh ok I didn't know it. when I declare char * s = cste it takes as a constant.
Thank you

Comment: @tonyjk C standard is really nasty sometimes. It's not a given that "test" is in read only memory, but it **may be**. So, just to be safe, use `const` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Note: In your posted code, the variable `j` is not declared, but is initialized to `0`. This will not compile.  Declare it and use it.  You will need two points of reference to do what you are attempting to do. (See comments in solution code example below for reason.)

Other observations:

The loop is infinite only when there are two successive numbers in the string.  eg if `str` = "asdf1234", then `str[4]` is changed to contain the value of `str[5]`, which is also a diget.  Because `i` is not incremented, the next test of `str[4]` will find it still remains a digit, and result in the same assignment to the value in `str[5]`.  So `str` becomes `"asdf2234"`, and remains that value, in an infinite loop.

In the case where numbers are not sequential, eg `str` = "asdf1a3a", even though the algorithm eventually exits the loop, the resulting string replaces any digits with the value contained in the following position, so the resulting string would look like: `"asdfaaaa"`.  I assume by *"tries to* ***remove*** *non alphabetic characters"* you would prefer the string be: `"asdfaa"`

Why:
Note the [continue](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_continue_statement.htm) statement in C programming works somewhat like the break statement. Instead of forcing termination, it forces the next iteration of the loop to take place, *skipping any code in between*.

So in your code, once the conditions bring execution flow to the `continue` statement, `i++` cannot be incremented preventing the exit condition in the `while` statement from ever being satisfied, and the flow is limited to the following four lines infinitely:

```
...
while (str[i]!='\0')
... //then 
if ((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') || (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'))
... //finally
 str[i]= str[i+1];
 continue;//then continues back to the beginning of while loop
```

Because `i` is not advanced (Note `str[i]= str[i+1];` does not change `i`), The only elements of the string array beyond that point that are observed will remain `str[i]`.

Following code removes digits from a string that contains them, regardless of whether the digits are sequential or not.  Additionally, this example will shorten the string to contain only remaining non-numeric characters:

```
int Removenonalfa(char *str) 
{
     int i,j;//using both i AND j in this example
     for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
     while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {//walking through original string
                                             //looking only for digits
         for (j = i; str[j] != '\0'; ++j) {//here we use j to track the next
                                           //occurrence to be changed so 
                                           //i does not change. 
            str[j] = str[j + 1];//digit found, overwrite it with
                                //next value in array.
         }
         str[j] = '\0';//after advancing characters to fill position
                       //formerly occupied by digit, terminate new
                       //string
      }
   }
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I tried to put j=1 between the statement and the continue; however the j was never equal to 1. I did a debug using codeblocks software.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop gets stuck in a loop when more that one consecutive character fails the test.

Consider the string `"A12"` containing consecutive characters `'1'` and `'2'` that fail the test:

```
iter   i   str[i]   str[i+1]   str[i+2]   str[i+3]
----   --  ------   --------   --------   --------
1       0   'A'      '1'        '2'        '\0'
2       1   '1'      '2'        '\0'       N/A
3       1   '2'      '2'        '\0'       N/A
4       1   '2'      '2'        '\0'       N/A
```

Iterations 4 onwards are just repeating iteration 3.

One way to fix it is to use two indices, one for the source character position and one for the destination character position:

```
int Removenonalfa(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    while (str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if ((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') || (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'))
            ;
        else
        {
            str[i]= str[j];
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Consider the string `"A12"`:

```
iter   i   str[i]   str[i+1]   str[i+2]   str[i+3]  j   str[j]   str[j+1]  str[j+2]
----   --  ------   --------   --------   --------  --  ------   --------  --------
1       0   'A'      '1'        '2'        '\0'      1   '1'      '2'       '\0'
2       1   '1'      '2'        '\0'       N/A       2   '2'      '\0'      N/A
3       1   '2'      '2'        '\0'       N/A       3   '\0'     N/A       N/A
4       1   '\0'     '2'        '\0'       N/A       4   N/A      N/A       N/A
```

The `while` loop terminates at the start of iteration 4 because `str[i]` equals `'\0'`. `str[0]` contains `'A'` and `str[1]` contains `'\0'`. (`str[2]` contains `'2'` and `str[3]` contains `'\0'`, but those do not matter.)

Demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Removenonalfa(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    while (str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if ((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') || (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'))
            ;
        else
        {
            str[i]= str[j];
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] Before: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        Removenonalfa(argv[i]);
        printf("[%d] After: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run: `./a.out A12 abcde 12345`

Output:

```
[1] Before: A12
[1] After: A
[2] Before: abcde
[2] After: abcde
[3] Before: 12345
[3] After:
```

N.B. The modification of `main()`'s `argv[]` string contents is allowed by the C standard, ref. C17 5.1.2.2.1/2: *— The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.*

Calling the function `Removenonalfa` with a pointer to a string literal will result in *undefined behavior*. See C17 6.4.5/7 regarding the unnamed character array used to store a string literal: *It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: I tried your code and it is not giving any result. It still stuck on this line 
str[i]= str[j];

Check the link online:
https://onlinegdb.com/OTvwTDZ9U

Comment: @tonyjk Your online example has *undefined behavior* because it modifies a string literal. Try it with `char c[] = "abcde";`. See the demonstration above that abuses the fact that command line string contents are writable.

Comment: @tonyjk - make sure that you are compiling and running the right code.  It appears from several comments in this post that your compiler is pointing to your original code, or some variation of it as opposed to the example code of those  that people who have answered